# the loop inside test method doesn't run

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng

I just write a for loop inside a test method (testNG) hoping that when the test run the loop also run with a complete iteration but the loop inside the test run only once 
actually, I cannot figure out why the loop ran only once?

[image: code example]

Comment: Please paste your code as text instead of an image. It makes it easier for us to help you that way.

Comment: + it's better for later searching

Comment: [I downvoted because images of code are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), and because [you're being unresponsive to comments](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive).

Answer (score 0):

Your loop only runs once because of your declaration:

`for (int i=1; i<2; i++)`

After the first iteration, `i` will be increased to `2`. This will cause for the loop to terminate as `i<2` is no longer true.

Comment: I updated the picture, however, this is not the problem even when i made it to iterate 4 times it just run one time

Comment: @MohammedAhmedMohammed Please paste the code as text, not as a picture. Also, seeing the little bit of code you have provided, I doubt it is enough to spot the cause of your problem as we do not know when/where this function is called.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that after the first loop, you are logged in. For the second loop the login page is not loaded again, no session is thrown away and you are already logged in. It is probably that because of this, you are not on the correct page for the loop to continue and somewhere there will be an exception.